# have issue in run jetty server

Tags: hibernate, maven, jetty

Have issue while running jetty Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@49cb5030[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWxNT.png)

Comment: hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. please post the **whole** exception and not a screenshopt of it where the important messages are missing.

Comment: Keep in mind that the jetty-maven-plugin and the jetty dependencies should have the same version.   It seems that you are using [an ancient version](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html) of jetty-maven-plugin (6.1.26), and Spring (which dropped support for for the End-of-Life Jetty 6 over eight years ago)